# Talend Open Studio: Load input files into database

Tags: sql, database, input, talend

I have an empty SQLlite database. Next to that, I have 6 input files (delimited, excel, json, xml).

Now, all I want to do is load the input files into the **empty** database.
I tried to connect one input file with the DB and just run it. That didn't work (the DB doens't have anything in it, I suspect that is a problem).

Then, I tried to connect an input file with a tMap, define the table there, define the schema and connect the tMap to the DB (tSQLliteOutput).

[image: Job design]

When I tried to run it, I receive the following error:

```
Starting job ProductDemo_Load at 16:46 15/11/2015.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3843
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tSQLiteOutput_1
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: 
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
    at workshop_test.productdemo_load_0_1.ProductDemo_Load.tFileInputExcel_1Process(ProductDemo_Load.java:751)
    at workshop_test.productdemo_load_0_1.ProductDemo_Load.runJobInTOS(ProductDemo_Load.java:1672)
    at workshop_test.productdemo_load_0_1.ProductDemo_Load.main(ProductDemo_Load.java:1529)
[statistics] disconnected
Job ProductDemo_Load ended at 16:46 15/11/2015. [exit code=1]
```

I see there's something wrong with the import, but what exactly?
What should I do in order to succesfully load the data from the input files in the database?

I did the exact steps from this little tutorial:
[Talend Job: load data into database.](http://www.talendbyexample.com/my-first-talend-job.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most talend output components have create table if not exists option.. Did u checked this in your tsqliteoutput..error seems that when talend is inserting data into empty database your table it is not able to find it as it does not exists.. So you to tell talend to create the table first..

Comment: Ok: just to clarify: select the tSQLliteOutput component, enter a tablename and choose "Drop table if exists and create" as action on table. Thanks!